# Null pointer Exception: GestureDetector.onTouchEvent for custom gallery in android for ICS 4.0

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, gallery, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In one of my android app, I am using custom gallery to show images in gallery .
(I am using custom gallery in order to show 1 item a time when swapping the gallery)

Here is the code that I am using for custom gallery :

```
public class CustomGallery extends Gallery {

     public CustomGallery(Context context) {
            super(context); 
        }

        public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

    private boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2) {
        return e2.getX() > e1.getX();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        int kEvent;
        if (isScrollingLeft(e1, e2)) { // Check if scrolling left
            kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT;
        } else { // Otherwise scrolling right
            kEvent = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT;
        }
        onKeyDown(kEvent, null);
        return true;

    }
}
```

The above code is working fine 2.2,2.3 etc.... but its **crashing in ICS 4.0 causing  Null pointer Exception   GestureDetector.onTouchEvent** .

Please help .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I just noticed that the problem was not because .... of custom gallery or all these .....The problem is due to the tab host ....when I am trying to start actvity using StartActvity() method it does not crashes but when I start the actvity as a child of current activity ..within the tab host ..the crashes comes .... Can any one have soome idea on this as I must need to start this as a child not as a singleActvity....here is my code: **Intent i = new Intent(A.this, A_Detail.class);
    
TabGroupActivity parent=(TabGroupActivity) getParent();
   
(parent).startChildActivity(PLAT_PAGE_ID, i);**

Answer (score 2):

I had this same sporadic problem. The two `MotionEvent` parameters that is passed to the override `onFling` method are sometimes null and calling `e2.getX()` throws the exception. You can fix this by starting your onFling method like this:

```
if (e1 == null || e2 == null) return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem only happening on ICS4.0 - my `Gallery` `View` was opening an `Activity` within the `TabHost` when user clicks an item on the `Gallery` - it was always giving `NullPointerException` but only on ICS4 - I ended up doing the following which did the trick:

```
//flag returned by onTouch event always false except when we are about to start activity
boolean flag = false;
//add a touch listener
myGallery.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return flag;
    }
});

myGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    //handle clicks

    //set flag returned by touch listener to true
    flag = true;

    //now add logic to open up the activity
 }
```

The Exception has now gone on ICS4.